# How to print part of an Array PHP

Tags: php, arrays, string

I call a function to get an array and use `var_dump()`

the result is the following array:

```
array(1) {
    [0]=> array(12) {
        ["access_id"] => string(1) "1"
        ["invoice_id"] => NULL
        ["invoice_public_id"] => NULL
        ["invoice_payment_id"] => NULL
        ["invoice_item_id"] => NULL
        ["user_id"] => string(1) "1"
        ["product_id"] => string(1) "2"
        ["transaction_id"] => NULL
        ["begin_date"] => string(10) "2015-12-24"
        ["expire_date"] => string(10) "2016-01-24"
        ["qty"] => string(1) "1"
        ["comment"] => string(0) ""
    } 
}
```

I only need this part :

```
["product_id"]=> string(1) "2"
```

How can i get that part only from the array?

Comment: If you only want `product_id` you can just use a simple echo to print the key and value in that specific format. `var_dump()` is a debugging function to show the entire array.

Comment: Please: 1. format your code; 2. read the [docs on php arrays](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php)

Comment: echo $array[1]['product_id']; I guess

Comment: echo $array[0]['product_id']; Yes mate this is correct. I was doing it like this : echo $array['product_id'][0]; and it wasn't working. Thanks a lottt.

Comment: @jamesll So you just want to access the `product_id`, it's not about that specific format?

Comment: @Rizier123 No no i just wanted the "2" at the end. I am noob.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply access the value directly:

```
echo $myArray[0]['product_id'];
```

You may want to start reading the documentation about arrays in php: 
http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php

Comment: Yes thanks a lottttt. This solved my problem.

Answer (score -1):

var_dump($yourArray[0]['product_id']);

You should not use var_dump for production, only for debugging.

Comment: This will give OP an undefined index

Comment: Yes rizier123 is right.It gave me NULL.

Comment: Undefined index fixed.